# Referencing and indexing other dataframe in dplyr mutate workflow

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe that computes something based on "matched" variables in another dataframe.

I know I can do this with `apply`, but it is the only workflow I haven't figured out how to perform in `dplyr`, and I'd like to find a tidy solution.

I've created a data frame `df1` with groups (random animals), years, and some statistic. I'd like to mutate a new column in this dataframe that calculates something using that statistic and the output dataframe from a set of linear models (`df2`).

```
# generate reprex df1 
year <- seq(1990, 2010, 1)
group <- c("giraffe","rhino","flamingo","shark","turtle")
df1 <- expand.grid(year, group) %>% 
  rename(year = Var1,
         group = Var2) %>% 
  mutate(stat = runif(length(year),37,44))

# generate reprex df2 
term <- c("(Intercept)","y")
df2 <- expand.grid(year, term) %>% 
  rename(year = Var1,
         term = Var2) %>% 
  mutate(estimate = ifelse(term=="y", -runif(n(), 1.1, 1.3), runif(n(), 50, 60)))
```

I want to feed the `stat` column from `df1` into the equation *for each year* provided by `df2` using the equation for a line (`y=ax+b`). Note that both the intercept and the slope vary each year in `df2`. Conceptually, this would look like 
`mutate(result = df1$stat*df2$estimate[estimate=="y" and year==year of df1] + df2$estimate[estimate=="(Intercept)" and year==year of df1]`.

For example, for giraffes in 1993, this would be 39.58*(-1.23)+50.14=1.45 (left off some decimal places for readability).

How can I actually do this with dplyr?

Comment: Good practice is to include `set.seed(0)` at the top if you want us to see the same random numbers from `runif` or other random functions. i.e. my 1993 giraffes is not 39.58....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest to approach in `dplyr` if you can first get all the terms you need for your calculation into the row where you need it. `tidyr::spread` will make `y` and `(Intercept)` available to the row where it's needed, and `left_join` lets you append the matching data from `df1`, in this case based on matching years (the column both tables share).

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>%
  spread(term, estimate) %>%
  left_join(df1) %>%
  mutate(result = stat * y + `(Intercept)`)
```

Comment: thanks! this works for my reprex (so you did answer the question!), but it was actually a simplification of a much more complex set of dataframes for which a join probably won't work well. I was hoping for a different tidy solution but it sounds like I should either use non-dplyr language or hammer them into join-able formats.